# Four data classes to one common classes

Tags: java

I have a number of data classes that are similar but slightly different.  From these classes I set "common fields" then other "special fields" depending on the class.  I want to create a method to set the common fields (so I don't have to repeat code for each data type).

Right I have something like this:

```
public CommonDataClass getCommonFieldsFromClass1(class1 dataObj) {
     CommonDataClass out = new CommonDataClass();
     out.SetField1(data.getField1);

     return out;
}

public CommonDataClass getCommonFieldsFromClass2(class2 dataObj) {
     CommonDataClass out = new CommonDataClass();
     out.SetField1(data.getField1);
     return out;
}

...

public CommonDataClass getCommonFieldsFromClassN(classN dataObj) {
     CommonDataClass out = new CommonDataClass();
     out.SetField1(data.getField1);
     return out;
}
```

I would like something like this

```
public CommonDataClass getCommonFields(MysteryClass dataObj) {
     CommonDataClass out = new CommonDataClass();
     out.SetField1(data.getField1);
     return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce an abstract base class for `class1` ... `classN` and let the populating classes extend an abstract base class populating class which contains the code setting the common fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface `CommonFieldsInterface` (you should use a more descriptive name) that contains getters to all the common fields. All your similar classes would implement that interface.

The alternative is that all the similar classes would have a common base class containing the common fields, but that would be appropriate only if these classes represent objects of the same general type.

That said, you should consider whether you really need to create an instance of `CommonDataClass` and copy fields to it. Each method that handles the fields of `CommonDataClass` could simply be defined in the common interface or common base-class of those similar classes.